# Bizarre HTML problem. Inspector view different from source

Tags: html, html-parsing

I'm having a strange problem where the inspector is showing my head content in the body while source is normal. What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Could we have a link to your site with this code on it, or an excerpt of said code please?

Comment: Please state the browser you are using too.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a code error somewhere in your head: a missing or malformed closing tag for example.

Comment: I think this might have been an encoding issue. I switched to ANSI (as the doc was on UTF-8) and it's now appearing correctly~! (funny how you discover the issue only after its posted..!)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you've missed the closing `<head>`-tag. Maybe it's `<head>…<head>` in your HTML.